# Creating sub-menus inside sub-menu in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to add sub-menus inside a sub-menu ?
I mean , when I hover over a option in my menu , I want more sub-menus to show up.
I'm very sorry if I am unclear , I don't know how do I explain this , but
[here's an image(GIF) of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jnSB.gif) .is there any way to achieve this in tkinter ?

Here's the code

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
mainmenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = mainmenu)
test_menu = Menu(mainmenu , tearoff = False)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label = "Test Menu" , menu = test_menu)
test_menu.add_command(label = "Show Sub-menus           ")
mainloop()
```

Comment: You do it exactly the same way as you're already doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just keep going adding sub menus using `add_cascade`:

```py
sub_menu = Menu(test_menu, tearoff=False)
sub_menu.add_command(label='Submenu item 1')
sub_menu.add_command(label='Submenu item 2')

test_menu.add_cascade(label = 'Sub menu', menu=sub_menu)
```

[image: Tkinter window with a sub menu]

```py
sub_sub_menu = Menu(sub_menu, tearoff=False)
sub_sub_menu.add_command(label='Sub-submenu item 1')
sub_sub_menu.add_command(label='Sub-submenu item 2')

sub_menu.add_cascade(label='Sub-sub menu', menu=sub_sub_menu)
```

[image: Tkinter window with a sub-sub menu]

Comment: I got a question: how to get a list of ALL menus/submenus and how to add/delete them dynamically?